# Unable to get my head around Predicate isEqual method

Tags: java, predicate

In Java docs it is given -

```
Modifier and Type                      Method and Description
static <T> Predicate<T>                isEqual(Object targetRef)
                                       Returns a predicate that tests if two arguments are equal according to Objects.equals(Object, Object).
```

In https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-predicate-with-examples/

it is given -

> isEqual(Object targetRef) : Returns a predicate that tests if two arguments are equal according to Objects.equals(Object, Object).
>
> static  Predicate isEqual(Object targetRef)
> Returns a predicate that tests if two arguments are
> equal according to Objects.equals(Object, Object).
> T : the type of arguments to the predicate
> Parameters:
> targetRef : the object reference with which to
> compare for equality, which may be null
> Returns: a predicate that tests if two arguments
> are equal according to Objects.equals(Object, Object)

I can't get a grisp of what this `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` might be

I write the following code to try it out -

Class Fruits -

`Fruits.java` -

```
public class Fruits {
    private String fruit;

    public Fruits(String fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }

    public String getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }
}
```

Here, the other methods of predicate seem to be quite easy to understand -

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> containsApple = list -> {
            boolean myReturn = false;
            Iterator<Fruits> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Fruits fruits = iterator.next();
                String fruit = fruits.getFruit();
                if (fruit.equals("Apple")) {
                    myReturn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return myReturn;
        };
```

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> containsOrange = list -> {
            boolean myReturn = false;
            Iterator<Fruits> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Fruits fruits = iterator.next();
                String fruit = fruits.getFruit();
                if (fruit.equals("Orange")) {
                    myReturn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return myReturn;
        };
```

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> containsAppleAndOrange = list -> {
            return containsApple.and(containsOrange).test(list);
        };
```

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> containsAppleOrRange = list -> {
            return containsApple.or(containsOrange).test(list);
        };
```

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> notContainsApple = list -> {
            return containsApple.negate().test(list);
        };
```

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> notContainsOrange = list -> {
            return containsOrange.negate().test(list);
        };
```

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> notContainsAppleAndOrange = list -> {
            return containsAppleAndOrange.negate().test(list);
        };
```

```
Predicate<List<Fruits>> notContainsAppleOrOrange = list -> {
            return containsAppleOrRange.negate().test(list);
        };
```

Here I test it with following data -

```
        List<Fruits> list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Fruits("Apple"),
                new Fruits("Orange"),
                new Fruits("Mango"),
                new Fruits("Banana")
        ));

        List<Fruits> list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Fruits("Apple"),
                new Fruits("Mango"),
                new Fruits("Banana"),
                new Fruits("Berry")
        ));

        List<Fruits> list3 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Fruits("Orange"),
                new Fruits("Mango"),
                new Fruits("Banana"),
                new Fruits("Berry")
        ));
```

Result is as expected.

But in no way can I understand how to implement the `isEqual()` method -

To see that two arguments are equal are not I create another predicate -

```
redicate<List<Fruits>> containsApple2 = list -> {
            boolean myReturn = false;
            Iterator<Fruits> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Fruits fruits = iterator.next();
                String fruit = fruits.getFruit();
                if (fruit.equals("Apple")) {
                    myReturn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return myReturn;
        };
```

I try something like (without understanding why) -

```
System.out.println(Predicate.isEqual(containsApple).test(list1));
```

Output - `false`

Now what happened here?

```
System.out.println(Predicate.isEqual(containsApple2).test(containsApple));
```

Output - `false`

Now again what happened here?

So, how to exactly use this `isEqual` method?

Comment: I just want to know how isEqual() works, how to use it? I just tried some use but failed I guess

Comment: Please give an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Predicate.isEqual` is a factory method that creates predicates that test if a given thing is equal to the parameter passed in.

`Predicate.isEqual(containsApple)` creates a `Predicate<Predicate<List<Fruits>>>` that tests if a given thing is equal to `containsApple`. However, since `containsApple` refers to an instance created from a lambda, and nothing much is guaranteed about the equality of instances created from lambda expressions (See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4)), nothing much can be said about the result of calling `test` on it. The classes of the lambda instances may or may not implement `equals`, and `containsApple` may or may not be the same instance as `containsApple2`, depending on the implementation.

Rather than comparing lambda instances, a typical example of using `Predicate.isEqual` is:

```
Fruits apple = new Fruits("Apple");
Predicate<Fruits> isApple = Predicate.isEqual(apple);
// rather than this slightly longer version:
// Predicate<Fruits> isApple = x -> Objects.equals(x, apple);
```

Then you can pass `isApple` around, to other methods that take `Predicate`s, and/or call `test` on it. `isApple.test(apple)` would be true, `isApple.test(new Fruits("something else"))` would be false. I would also recommend that you override `equals` and `hashCode` in `Fruits`.

Note that we generally make predicates that test against individual objects, rather than lists (collections) of things. We would pass these predicates to other methods (such as `Stream.filter`), and let *them* do the filtering. For example, to filter a list to get all the apples:

```
List<Fruits> apples = fruitsList.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.isEqual(apple)).toList();
```

Answer (score 2):

One should use singular here for the class Fruits.

First you must establish *equality* of Fruit. Also should you ever want it to store in a HashMap or HashSet, a `hashCode` implementation is important.

```
public class Fruit {
    private final String fruit; // Or name.

    public Fruit(String fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }

    public String getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceOf Fruit && ((Fruit) other).fruit.equals(fruit);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return fruit.hashCode();
    }
}
```

The Iterator class is rather old and its primary advantage is you can walk through and still remove an element with `iterator.remove()`, which is not allowed on the List in a - statefull - for (ConcurrentModificationException).

```
Predicate<List<Fruit>> containsApple = list -> {
    for (Fruit fruit: list) {
        if (fruit.getFruit().equals("Apple")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

Predicate<List<Fruit>> containsApple = list -> list.contains(new Fruit("Apple"));
```

Advisable is to get acquainted with Stream (like *for* iterating through a collection) and its expressive power.

```
Predicate<List<Fruit>> containsApple = list ->
    list.stream()
        .anyMatch(fr -> fr.getFruit().equals("Apple"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @user16320675 in comments one of the simplest examples would be -

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer num1 = 2;
        Integer num2 = 3;
        Predicate<Integer> predicate = Predicate.isEqual(num1);
        System.out.println(predicate.test(num1));
        System.out.println(predicate.test(num2));
    }
}
```

Output -

```
true
false
```

The code can also be rewritten as -

```
        System.out.println(Predicate.isEqual(num1).test(num1));
        System.out.println(Predicate.isEqual(num1).test(num2));
```

with same output.

A practical application in Java streams -

Code -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Elephant");
        list.add("Hippo");
        list.add("Rhino");
        list.add("Deer");
        list.add("Hippo");
        list.add("Zebra");

        Predicate<String> predicate = Predicate.isEqual("Hippo");

        list.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output -

```
Hippo
Hippo
```